Bigtable Read and Write using DataProc with compute engine results in Key not found
I am experimenting with reading and writing data in cloud BigTable using the DataProc compute engine and PySpark Job using spark-bigtable-connector. I got an example from spark-bigtable repo and running the same example. But this results in Key Not Found. 
Command Used to run:

spark-submit --jars gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-3.4-bigquery-0.39.1.jar --jars gs://spark-lib/bigtable/spark-bigtable_2.12-0.1.1.jar  demo_file.py  --bigtableProjectId <> --bigtableInstanceId <> --bigtableTableName <> --createNewTable True

Below is the full trace for the mentioned error.
        at com.google.cloud.spark.bigtable.Logging.initializeLogging(Logging.scala:107)
        at com.google.cloud.spark.bigtable.Logging.initializeLogIfNecessary(Logging.scala:98)
        at com.google.cloud.spark.bigtable.Logging.initializeLogIfNecessary$(Logging.scala:94)
        at com.google.cloud.spark.bigtable.datasources.BigtableDataClientBuilder$.initializeLogIfNecessary(BigtableDataClientBuilder.scala:37)
        at com.google.cloud.spark.bigtable.Logging.log(Logging.scala:46)
        at com.google.cloud.spark.bigtable.Logging.log$(Logging.scala:44)
        at com.google.cloud.spark.bigtable.datasources.BigtableDataClientBuilder$.log(BigtableDataClientBuilder.scala:37)
        at com.google.cloud.spark.bigtable.Logging.logDebug(Logging.scala:58)
        at com.google.cloud.spark.bigtable.Logging.logDebug$(Logging.scala:57)
        at com.google.cloud.spark.bigtable.datasources.BigtableDataClientBuilder$.logDebug(BigtableDataClientBuilder.scala:37)
        at com.google.cloud.spark.bigtable.datasources.BigtableDataClientBuilder$.getHandle(BigtableDataClientBuilder.scala:68)
        at com.google.cloud.spark.bigtable.BigtableRelation.$anonfun$insert$2(BigtableDefaultSource.scala:164)
        at com.google.cloud.spark.bigtable.BigtableRelation.$anonfun$insert$2$adapted(BigtableDefaultSource.scala:162)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$foreachPartition$2(RDD.scala:1036)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$foreachPartition$2$adapted(RDD.scala:1036)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$5(SparkContext.scala:2455)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:95)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:476)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:594)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:527)
        ... 27 more

24/06/26 16:48:42 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.1 in stage 2.0 (TID 4) (cluster-adf5-w-1.us-central1-b.c.xxx.internal executor 2): java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: BigtableClientKey(  projectId = xxx,  instanceId = xxx,  appProfileId = default,  emulatorPort = None,  batchMutateFlowControl = false,  readRowsAttemptTimeout = None,  readRowsTotalTimeout = None,  mutateRowsAttemptTimeout = None,  mutateRowsTotalTimeout = None,  batchSize = 100,  userAgentText = spark-bigtable_2.12/0.1.1 spark/3.5.0 data source/V1 scala/2.12.18 )
        at scala.collection.MapLike.default(MapLike.scala:236)
        at scala.collection.MapLike.default$(MapLike.scala:235)
        at scala.collection.AbstractMap.default(Map.scala:65)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.apply(HashMap.scala:69)
        at com.google.cloud.spark.bigtable.datasources.BigtableDataClientBuilder$.getHandle(BigtableDataClientBuilder.scala:72)
        at com.google.cloud.spark.bigtable.BigtableRelation.$anonfun$insert$2(BigtableDefaultSource.scala:164)
        at com.google.cloud.spark.bigtable.BigtableRelation.$anonfun$insert$2$adapted(BigtableDefaultSource.scala:162)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$foreachPartition$2(RDD.scala:1036)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$foreachPartition$2$adapted(RDD.scala:1036)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$5(SparkContext.scala:2455)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:95)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

24/06/26 16:48:42 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/demo_file.py", line 97, in <module>
    .save()
     ^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 1461, in save
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/errors/exceptions/captured.py", line 179, in deco
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o109.save.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 2.0 (TID 6) (cluster-adf5-w-1.us-central1-b.c.xxx.internal executor 2): java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: BigtableClientKey(  projectId = xxx,  instanceId = xxx,  appProfileId = default,  emulatorPort = None,  batchMutateFlowControl = false,  readRowsAttemptTimeout = None,  readRowsTotalTimeout = None,  mutateRowsAttemptTimeout = None,  mutateRowsTotalTimeout = None,  batchSize = 100,  userAgentText = spark-bigtable_2.12/0.1.1 spark/3.5.0 data source/V1 scala/2.12.18 )
        at scala.collection.MapLike.default(MapLike.scala:236)
        at scala.collection.MapLike.default$(MapLike.scala:235)
        at scala.collection.AbstractMap.default(Map.scala:65)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.apply(HashMap.scala:69)
        at com.google.cloud.spark.bigtable.datasources.BigtableDataClientBuilder$.getHandle(BigtableDataClientBuilder.scala:72)
        at com.google.cloud.spark.bigtable.BigtableRelation.$anonfun$insert$2(BigtableDefaultSource.scala:164)
        at com.google.cloud.spark.bigtable.BigtableRelation.$anonfun$insert$2$adapted(BigtableDefaultSource.scala:162)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$foreachPartition$2(RDD.scala:1036)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$foreachPartition$2$adapted(RDD.scala:1036)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$5(SparkContext.scala:2455)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:95)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2844)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2780)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2779)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2779)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1242)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1242)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1242)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3048)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2982)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2971)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:984)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2415)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2436)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2455)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2480)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$foreachPartition$1(RDD.scala:1036)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:407)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreachPartition(RDD.scala:1034)
        at com.google.cloud.spark.bigtable.BigtableRelation.insert(BigtableDefaultSource.scala:162)
        at com.google.cloud.spark.bigtable.BigtableDefaultSource.createRelation(BigtableDefaultSource.scala:76)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:84)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:107)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:125)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:201)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:900)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:107)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:98)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:473)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(origin.scala:76)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:473)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:449)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:98)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:83)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:142)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:859)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:388)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:361)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:248)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: BigtableClientKey(  projectId = xxx,  instanceId = xxx,  appProfileId = default,  emulatorPort = None,  batchMutateFlowControl = false,  readRowsAttemptTimeout = None,  readRowsTotalTimeout = None,  mutateRowsAttemptTimeout = None,  mutateRowsTotalTimeout = None,  batchSize = 100,  userAgentText = spark-bigtable_2.12/0.1.1 spark/3.5.0 data source/V1 scala/2.12.18 )
        at scala.collection.MapLike.default(MapLike.scala:236)
        at scala.collection.MapLike.default$(MapLike.scala:235)
        at scala.collection.AbstractMap.default(Map.scala:65)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.apply(HashMap.scala:69)
        at com.google.cloud.spark.bigtable.datasources.BigtableDataClientBuilder$.getHandle(BigtableDataClientBuilder.scala:72)
        at com.google.cloud.spark.bigtable.BigtableRelation.$anonfun$insert$2(BigtableDefaultSource.scala:164)
        at com.google.cloud.spark.bigtable.BigtableRelation.$anonfun$insert$2$adapted(BigtableDefaultSource.scala:162)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$foreachPartition$2(RDD.scala:1036)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$foreachPartition$2$adapted(RDD.scala:1036)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$5(SparkContext.scala:2455)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:95)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        ... 1 more

Searched multiple sources and found no lead. Need a pointer to move forward on this.
